# where is best place to save application files in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, path

I am programming for **iOS** using **Objective-C**
what is the best place (I mean **path** or **local URL**) to save my **downloaded mp3 files** that I download using my code and what is the best place to save the **Plist file** that contains information about the downloaded songs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the nature of iOS (and app sandboxing), you can *only* save within your app's document directory. To obtain the path to this directory, you can use:

```
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

One advantage of the sandbox approach is the fact that when your app is updated on the device, the files in the document directory will remain untouched and hence can be updated by the app as required.

I'd recommend a read of the [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/Introduction/Introduction.html), as it covers this topic (and a lot more), including iCloud file management, etc.

Comment: NSDocumentDirectory is probably the right place to store the mp3 files. It should just be noted that this is not the *only* place in the sandbox where an iOS app can store files. For example, NSCachesDirectory (-> Library/Caches) would be used for files that can be re-created and should not be backed up to iCloud.

Answer (score 3):

For Document Directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

For Caches Directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *libDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

For tmp Directory:

```
NSString *tmpDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory();
```

Comment: I haven't thought it as you thought. It's developer-login only document, i am just trying to clear the usage of directories that apple recommended. I edit my answer. Thanks for your suggestion.